# How to use terraform to ignore previous execution(state)

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using terraform to create a bucket in s3,
I want to run my main.tf 3 times
Each time on a new env(dev, staging, prod)

So each time it will create a new bucket and won't override the bucket name
Based on the tf state

How I can I set my tf file to ignore the last state

Comment: By specifying a different state file each time. You will have 3 states, one for each environment.

Comment: Maybe use workspaces? It's unclear if you want a bucket for the state file or buckets used for something else.